# How to consume Kafka messages with human-readable timestamps in command line?

Tags: apache-kafka

I know `kafka-console-consumer` has a property `print.timestamp=true`, but it prints epoch time instead of human-readable time. How can I consume Kafka messages with human-readable timestamps in the command line?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible straight forward using `kafka-console-consumer` (`kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer`).

`kafka-console-consumer` to print messages uses `kafka.common.MessageFormatter`. Its responsibility is to based on properties print messages in human readable way. By default it uses `kafka.tools.DefaultMessageFormatter` implementation, that print timestamp as epoch time.

To print timestamp in *more readable* way I can see to options:

1. Implement your own `kafka.common.MessageFormatter` and set it in properties for `kafka-console-consumer` program (`--formatter CustomFormatterClassName`)
2. Parse timestamp *outside* `kafka-console-consumer` using bash/awk etc